# UITableView Checkmark Selecting One At A Time

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios4

I have a UITableView, and when a cell is pressed, a checkmark is displayed in the accessory view. However I want to only be able to have one checkmark displayed at any given time. How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you are comparing your data. This is how I use checkmarks for my tableView:

```
if([[plistDict objectForKey:@"Warranty"] boolValue] == YES) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}
```

You can also compare text:

```
if([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Some Text"]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}
```

Comment: No thats not what i meant. I am currently setting a checkmark to be shown when the user selects a row. But if the user selects another cell another checkmark is shown. I would only like to show one checkmark.